# I need to fix with code igniter query

Tags: sql, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, code-injection

I am trying to get details from table1 and table2 on basis of table3 id array.
table3 id and table1 ids are availale in table2.

// $ids is a array of ids like: Array ( [ids] => 10,11 )

```
function get_detail($ids) { 

    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('table1');
    $this->db->join('table2', 'table1.aID = table2.aID');
    $this->db->join('table3', 'table2.bID = table3.bID','left');
    $this->db->where('table3.bID', $ids); 
    $query = $this->db->get();      

}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you have multiple values you should use **IN**

Replace

```
$this->db->where();
```

With

```
$this->db->where_in();
```

Both takes (col, value);

Note : // $ids  = Array ( 10,11 );

Answer (score 0):

Hello you use **where_in** like this

```
function get_detail($ids) { 

    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('table1');
    $this->db->join('table2', 'table1.aID = table2.aID');
    $this->db->join('table3', 'table2.bID = table3.bID','left');
    $this->db->where_in('table3.bID', $ids); 
    $query = $this->db->get();      

}
```

**Note :**  Pass $ids in array format

$ids = Array (10,11);

Comment: How can i use foreach() for array like 

    Array ( [sectionIDs] => 1,2,3,4 ) 

or how can i break Array ( [sectionIDs] => 1,2,3,4 )  into `Array ( [0] => 1,[1] => 2,[2] => 3,[3] => 4 )`

Answer (score 0):

you can use an array

```
$array = array('name !=' => $name, 'id <' => $id, 'date >' => $date);

$this->db->where($array);
```

Comment: How can i use foreach() for array like 

    Array ( [sectionIDs] => 1,2,3,4 ) 

or how can i break Array ( [sectionIDs] => 1,2,3,4 )  into `Array ( [0] => 1,[1] => 2,[2] => 3,[3] => 4 )`